# How to calculate Altitude from IMU?

Tags: imu

How to calculate attitude from IMU ?

For example, mathematical equations

Comment: I assume you meant to ask how to calculate *attitude*, not altitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altitude is usually determined from pressure and temperature sensors of an IMU.  You can see a formula [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/kinetic/barfor.html).

However, you must realize that raw data from a sensor is NEVER RELIABLE.  Sensors do not always give a correct reading.  Instead, they give you a value somewhat close to the true value, but with some random "noise" added to it.  So, instead of just using the data that you obtain from the sensor, you should always filter out the noise using some form of kalman filter.

Comment: Can i have your Email for personal contact @paul

Comment: @xsari3x:  I am, by no means, an expert at these kinds of things.  It's better to keep on posting your questions here on the robotics SE site.  If i can't answer your question, it is likely that someone else can.

Comment: Are there IMUs available that include pressure and temperature sensors?

Comment: @Ian: Some do, but not normally.  I would say that it's more common that the altimeter sensors are separate from the IMU.

Answer (score 1):

An aircraft's [attitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_dynamics_(fixed-wing_aircraft)) can be calculated from an IMU, but a full-fledged [Attitude and Heading Reference System (AHRS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attitude_and_heading_reference_system) needs a bit more data -- magnetometers and GPS sensors can help.  Your question is a little vague as to what you're hoping to accomplish.

Here is [an article describing some of the code you need in order to do this](http://www.camelsoftware.com/firetail/blog/c/imu-maths/) with [quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation), but in general there's not much I can suggest besides searching for "IMU attitude estimation".

Comment: Based on the OP's recent questions, it's highly likely that he meant to say 'attitude' (with a T), but as it is written, he's asking for 'altitude' (with an L).

Comment: I meant altitude , but thanks your answer still a great reference

Comment: Hmm... then the short answer is "you *don't* calculate altitude from an IMU".  You just measure it directly with a pressure sensor or [altimeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altimeter).